# Why I can’t find any benefit of caching LINQ to Entity query?

Tags: entity-framework, caching

Please look at my sourcecode.

```
public class EntityQuery
{
    public static Func<AdventureWork2008Container, IQueryable<SalesPerson>> selectQuery = CompiledQuery.Compile
    (
        (AdventureWork2008Container aw) =>
        (
            from s in aw.SalesPerson
            join e in aw.Employee on s.BusinessEntityID equals e.BusinessEntityID
            join p in aw.Person on s.BusinessEntityID equals p.BusinessEntityID
            join bea in aw.BusinessEntityAddress on s.BusinessEntityID equals bea.BusinessEntityID
            join a in aw.Address on bea.AddressID equals a.AddressID
            join sp in aw.StateProvince on a.StateProvince equals sp
            select s
        )
    );

    public decimal Select(AdventureWork2008Container aw)
    {
        SalesPerson result = selectQuery(aw).First();
        return result.SalesYTD;
    }

    public decimal Select2(AdventureWork2008Container aw)
    {            
        SalesPerson result =
        (
            from s in aw.SalesPerson
            join e in aw.Employee on s.BusinessEntityID equals e.BusinessEntityID
            join p in aw.Person on s.BusinessEntityID equals p.BusinessEntityID
            join bea in aw.BusinessEntityAddress on s.BusinessEntityID equals bea.BusinessEntityID
            join a in aw.Address on bea.AddressID equals a.AddressID
            join sp in aw.StateProvince on a.StateProvince equals sp
            select s
        ).First();

        return result.SalesYTD;
    }
}
```

I try to call Select method about 1000 times and call Select2 method about 1000 times. But the result shows me that Select2 method is a bit faster than Select method about 0.005 s.(0.052/0.057 s.) Moreover, this capture doesn't include time for creating EntityQuery object.

What's wrong with my source code?

PS. the following code show how to call methods.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (AdventureWork2008Container aw = new AdventureWork2008Container())
        {
            EntityQuery eq = new EntityQuery();

            eq.Select(aw);
            long lastTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                eq.Select(aw);
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add("Select 1 : " + ShowTime(lastTime));
        }

        GC.Collect();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (AdventureWork2008Container aw = new AdventureWork2008Container())
        {
            EntityQuery eq = new EntityQuery();

            eq.Select2(aw);
            long lastTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                eq.Select2(aw);
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add("Select 2 : " + ShowTime(lastTime));
        }

        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Select2() generated code is

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ...
```

In Select() aggregating is done on top of request. Don't know for sure, but it could lead to .Compile() results being discarded.

Try to move .First() into the compiled query.

```
public static Func<AdventureWork2008Container, SalesPerson> selectQuery = CompiledQuery.Compile
(
    (AdventureWork2008Container aw) =>
    (
        from s in aw.SalesPerson
        join e in aw.Employee on s.BusinessEntityID equals e.BusinessEntityID
        join p in aw.Person on s.BusinessEntityID equals p.BusinessEntityID
        join bea in aw.BusinessEntityAddress on s.BusinessEntityID equals bea.BusinessEntityID
        join a in aw.Address on bea.AddressID equals a.AddressID
        join sp in aw.StateProvince on a.StateProvince equals sp
        select s
    ).First();
);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks. I try it. It works! In select top 1 case, cached query is faster than non-cached query about 17 times. Moreover, in select all case; cached query is faster than non-cached query about 3 times (I think most of time is spent for fetching data).